# Cannot resolve "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error. Can someone check my code?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, swiftui

I'm relatively new to SwiftUI and time to time getting errors and solving them by searching over the internet but this time I could not find any solution to my problem and decided to ask for some help over here, stack overflow. I hope the code below helps you to find my issue.

Both my struct are Identifiable and I actually used ShoppingList struct in the same view to make a List of it with the same technique and it works without an error. But when I try to use ForEach for a variable of ShoppingList struct (which is also a struct and conforms to Identifiable protocol) I get this error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

**This is the view that I get my error:**

```
struct ListDetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    var item: ShoppingList
    @State private var isAddNewViewActive: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Products")) {
                ForEach(self.item.products, id: \.id) { product in <<<--- ERROR LINE
                        Text(product.name)
                    }
            }
            Section(header: Text("")) {
                Button(action: { self.isAddNewViewActive.toggle() } ) {
                    Text("Click to add new product")
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        .navigationBarTitle(self.item.name)
        .sheet(isPresented: $isAddNewViewActive) {
            AddNewItemView(session: self.session, item: self.item, isViewActive: self.$isAddNewViewActive)
        }
    }
}
```

**These are the structs that are in the code**

```
struct ShoppingList: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var coverPhoto: String
    var products: [Product]

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, coverPhoto: String = "cart", products: [Product] = [Product]()) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.coverPhoto = coverPhoto
        self.products = products
    }

    mutating func addProduct(product: Product) {
        products.append(product)
        print(products)
    }

}

struct Product: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var brand: String
    var imageURL: String
    var links: [Int: String]
    var description: String

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, brand: String = "", imageURL: String = "", links: [Int: String] = [:], description: String = "") {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.brand = brand
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.description = description
        self.links = links
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to all StackOverflow Community.

Answer (score 0):

i properly conform to the Equatable protocol

```
struct ShoppingList: Identifiable, Equatable {
        static func == (lhs: ShoppingList, rhs: ShoppingList) -> Bool {
            return lhs.id == rhs.id && rhs.id == lhs.id
        }
        var id: UUID()
        ...
        init(name: String, brand: String = "", imageURL: String = "", links: [Int: String] = [:], description: String = "") {
            ...
        }
    }
```

no need to init UUID, UUID() will self generate

Comment: ForEach(self.item.products) { product in 
                        Text(product.name)
                    }

Comment: return lhs.id == rhs.id && rhs.id == lhs.id ? Before answering, check your answer please ...

Comment: I need to initialise id values for some cases but tried not doing it for this case to see if that causes the error and it didn't solve the issue. I didn't understand the Equatable part of your answer.

Comment: if your type has an id property that uniquely identifies an entity, you need implement properly

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there was an error in a completely unrelated part of the code snippet I posted here (sheet View that pops when I click the button on View that has error) and that was causing the error :/

The code I posted here works just fine.